# AWS Security group rule for certbot renewal

Tags: amazon-web-services, certbot

I want to add a rule to my `aws` security group to allow for incoming traffic from the acme server (I guess it is `acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org`) to issue and automate the renewal of my cert;

What is the best way of doing this, given that sg rules do not support hostnames but only IPs?

Comment: Wildcard (0.0.0.0) is definitely an option provided that  security measures are taken care.

Answer (score 3):

You just can **not** because from Let's Encrypt FAQ:

> - **What IP addresses does Let’s Encrypt use to validate my web server?**
>
>   We don’t publish a list of IP addresses we use to validate, because
>     they may change at any time. In the future we may validate from
>     multiple IP addresses at once.

You will need a reverse proxy (usually a WAF), routing /.well-know/acme to a machine and answering the challenges (from anywhere) and doing the IP filtering before forwarding to your application all other requests.